# stackstatus shows the same message twice

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, stackstatus

https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/63386951108/we-are-back-online-after-a-build-caused-some
https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/61776482244/we-are-spinning-up-our-oregon-data-center-now
https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/61709132246/search-is-now-back-online-stackoverflow

Is showing the message twice in the main area.

[image]

It seems to be an issue with the query or page generation since the content contains the dup, from the source:

```
<section class="quote medium_text larger_text">
    <span>“</span>We are back online after a build caused some locking that wasn&#8217;t intended, sorry about that #stackoverflow We are back online after a build caused some locking that wasn&#8217;t intended, sorry about that #stackoverflow”
</section>
```

Comment: It seems it does. It seems it does.

Comment: I really hope this wasn't the result of a race condition.

Comment: @Bart A clear case of a duplicate@Bart A clear case of a duplicate

Comment: It would be funny if this question was closed as a duplicate. :PIt would be funny if this question was closed as a duplicate. :P

Comment: Vincent Twice, Vincent Twice.

Comment: I honestly hadn't heard about StackStatus until now.

Comment: I honestly hadn't heard about StackStatus until now.

Comment: Why I can't upvote this question twice? Why I can't upvote this question twice?

Comment: That's probably case of oscillating localization. :)

Comment: Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo

Answer (score 4):

We were using a service to echo quick twitter notifications there but that seems buggy, I have deactivated it for now and will try and find another alternative for those after an RSS feed.

Comment: Hey, any updates almost two years later? :)